# Export a table from SQL to a flat text file without using a wizard?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm wondering is it possible to export a table from Microsoft SQl without having to use the Export Wizard? At the moment I find it a very time consuming process when having to export multiple files.

Comment: You will probably need a different SQL tool.

Comment: I take it there's no equivalent of say Bulk Insert but for exporting files

Comment: `bcp` can do that I'm not mistaken

Comment: The `bcp` command like utility (from which quite a bit of bulk insert, such as format files, comes from) offers export as well as import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for configuration one time only

```
   EXEC [DataBase].dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   EXEC [DataBase].dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
   RECONFIGURE
```

Where `[DataBase]` is your Database name

Now for exporting data please try this

```
  EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [DataBase].dbo.[TABLE_NAME]" queryout "C:\exportfilename.txt" -T -c -t,'
```

Where `[DataBase]`  is your database name and `[TABLE_NAME]` is your table name.

You will get the exported data to the path `C:\exportfilename.txt` of your server.